# How to add Go to App button on my app page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have a facebook page for the app. if i open the page, it just show like button. i need "Go To App" button near by, which will redirect the user to the facebook app. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not ever merge pages! I did it and I regret. You'll lose everything. You can simply just change page type to Brands & Products > App Page, and you can choose it in the app settings thereafter. That simple!