# Getting error adding "Go to app" button to my Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I want the "Go to app" button on my Facebook page like this:

[image]

Mine currently looks like this:

[image]

As mentioned in [How to add Go to App button on my app page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922287/how-to-add-go-to-app-button-on-my-app-page), I tried using the following URL to add the button to my Facebook page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=APP_URL
```

Instead, I got this error:

[image]

Where's my button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe 'Go To App' button is only on Pages which are linked directly with an app (i.e the page representing the app itself, not a page upon which the app is installed as a tab) - you can create such a page for your app in the app's advanced settings. Don't change the page category from 'App' or it'll remove the link